# console not show in Proxmox

Tags: java, proxmox

I'm using `PROXMOX`, but i can't access to java console

Error :

```
no connection : Connection timed out
TASK ERROR: command '/bin/nc -l -p 5900 -w 10 -c '/usr/sbin/qm vncproxy 119 2>/dev/null'' failed: exit code 1
```

browser : `google chrome` / `Firefox`

Java -version :  `java version "1.6.0_30"`

OS : `ubuntu 12.04`

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: it's a java issue, reinstall SUN JAVA